# How to make icemegamenu submenu item to always show

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla, module

I need to always show the items of a submenu item when in hover state but I can't seem to find out what hides the submenu items in question. For precision, I need the iceMenuLiLevel_3 (and children levels) to be always displaying once the first menu item is in hover state.

The items are not display:hidden on mouse out.

Just how are the submenu items hidden in Joomla 3 with Icemegamenu?

Comment: Just found out that the CSS property that was used was visibility and hidden was inherited on ul.icesubMenu so I tried to make inline CSS to make the submenu always appear but it does not work...

Comment: Opacity was also in play, that's why sub-menu items weren't appearing.

Comment: can you please create a fiddle for this??